# script behaves differently via cron and command prompt

Tags: cron

I have a script that checks if second argument is numeric or not. When i pass numeric value in second argument and run manually in command prompt the script works. if i invoke same command via cron then the line that checks for numeric value tells me that second argument is not numeric.

Code that is checking numeric value: `if [[ $2 =~ ^[\-0-9]+$ ]]`

Answer (score 0):

Please start your script with a `#!/bin/bash` and then

Try to add

`source ~/.bashrc`

after the line `#!/bin/bash`.

Your `crontab` entry should look like:

e.g
`00 17 * * * /ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/YOUR/SCRIPT`

This is to run the script everyday 5 PM

Comment: i tried both these options but still getting same error.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and give the full code and crontab entry?